# Getting error while importing the fields in Google Analytics Reports module

Tags: views, google-analytics

I have installed [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module latest version, enabled the GA reports data API and created a service account credentials on developer console. Then I have downloaded the json file of service account and uploaded in the GA reports module configs and also added the property id. But now when I am importing the fields I am getting this error. [image]

I have checked the logs also and it says **"Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'conversions:click' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO "google_analytics_reports_fields".**

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this error was coming because I have created multiple conversions on my google analytics that's why it was throwing 'Duplicate entry 'conversions:click' error. So I deleted one conversion:click from GA and then successfully imported the fields.